# How to prevent one model having many models in OneToOne relationship? [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

Let's say I have 2 tables, cars and owners, where a car can have one owner and an owner can have one car.

However if I execute:

```php
$owner = App\Owner::first();
$owner -> car() -> create(['color' => 'red']);
$owner -> car() -> create(['color' => 'green']);
```

I would end up with:

```php
Car {
    id: "1",
    color: "red",
    owner_id: "1",
},
Car {
    id: "2",
    color: "green",
    owner_id: "1",
},
```

And now the owner 1 has two cars, how I can prevent that? and for example, update the row or at least throw an error when trying to add the second car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really resolve stuck a thing automatically when creating the models.

However, there are 2 options:
1: perform a check on the database before creating the model, as part of your code.
2: make the `owner_id` column `unique` inside the database table (add a unique index to it).

Option 2 is the more automated way, but is very unforgiving. Option 1 is more flexible but requires more strict coding discipline.